# Issue deploying Django app onto Heroku due to twisted-iocpsupport

Tags: python, heroku, twisted

I am trying to deploy a Django app I've made onto Heroku. After finally figuring out how to push it to git, I tried doing

$ git push heroku master

But then it fails to push because it can't build the 'twisted_iocpsupport.iocpsupport' extension.

The error message I get is as follows.

```
remote: creating build

remote: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9

remote: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/twisted_iocpsupport

remote: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Itwisted_iocpsupport -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -c twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.o

remote: twisted_iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c:633:10: fatal error: io.h: No such file or directory

remote: 633 | #include "io.h"

remote: | ^~~~~~

remote: compilation terminated.

remote: error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1

remote: ----------------------------------------

remote: ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted-iocpsupport

remote: Successfully built foil gunicorn Protego PyDispatcher

remote: Failed to build twisted-iocpsupport

remote: ERROR: Could not build wheels for twisted-iocpsupport which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How do I fix this? I tried removing Twisted and twisted_iocpsupport from my requirements.txt file just to see if it would push, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

`twisted_iocpsupport` is a platform-specific module for Windows only.  You won't be able to build or install it on Heroku's Linux-based platform.

Remove whatever declaration you have that `twisted_iocpsupport` is a dependency of your project and this should go away.